# javafx - Bind button according to boolean value

Tags: button, javafx, boolean, bind, disabled-input

Here, I want to disable and enable button according to the value of the boolean.

```
boolean result=(txtItem.getText().isEmpty() && txtQty.getText().isEmpty());

btnOrder.disableProperty().bind(xxxxx);
```

what should I enter there??

Comment: Can you provide more detail? You want `btnOrder` to be disabled when the value computed by `result` becomes true? Are `txtItem` and `txtQty` text fields, or something similar?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking (in particular, assuming `txtItem` and `txtQty` are some kind of `TextInputControl`), you can do

```
btnOrder.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(
    () -> txtItem.getText().isEmpty() && txtQty.getText().isEmpty(),
    txtItem.textProperty(), txtQty.textProperty()));
```

or

```
btnOrder.disableProperty().bind(
    Bindings.length(txtItem.textProperty()).isEqualTo(0)
    .and(Bindings.length(txtQty.textProperty()).isEqualTo(0)));
```

Comment: And if I want to check the values.. lets say if the value of txtItem is less than the value of txtQty, then button must enable

Comment: @kasun Just include that condition in the evaluation function in the first version. (If you're converting the text to numeric values, then I don't think there's an equivalent of the second version that will work.)